# Cannot detect checkbox click or change event with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

It's a real mystery, but somehow I cannot detect checkbox click or change with the following code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
   jQuery(document).on("click", "#item_configuration_item_selected", function() {
      console.log("click");
   });
});
```

It works with any other element, but not checkboxes.

When I try to detect the clicked element with this:

```
jQuery('body').click(function(event){ 
    var id = event.target;
    console.log(id);
});
```

then again, it shows a clicked element id for any other element, except checkbox. I'm just going crazy figuring this out.

Element html looks like this:

```
<div class="span3">
<label for="item_configuration_item_selected" class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" class="fabrikinput " name="item_configuration_item_selected[0][0]" id="item_configuration_item_selected" value="1"><span>MyLabel</span></label>
</div>
```

Any hint would be highly appreciated.

**Edit added snippet**

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery(document).on("click", "#item_configuration_item_selected", function() {
    console.log("click");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="span3">
  <label for="item_configuration_item_selected" class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" class="fabrikinput " name="item_configuration_item_selected[0][0]" id="item_configuration_item_selected" value="1"><span>MyLabel</span></label>
</div>
```

Comment: `$("#item_configuration_item_selected").change(function() {})` Did you tired this?

Comment: If i create a snippet with your code all work

Comment: Do you have more than one element with id `item_configuration_item_selected`?  Do you have any css?  Eg that turns off pointer events?

Comment: As with comment above, I've added a snippet using your code and it works fine.   Please update the snippet to *demonstrate* the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all, but Prakash's suggestion "$("#item_configuration_item_selected").change(function() {})" was the only thing that worked. Thank you so much! I'm still confused why, but as long as it does the trick, I can live with that :)

Comment: As you were using event delegation, then there may have been another event in the chain that did stopPropagation (or return false) before it got to your event.  Impossible to tell in isolation.